# Convert SVG Elliptical arc into UibezierPath curve

Tags: objective-c, uibezierpath, bezier

Is it possible to generate a UIBezierPath Curve from an SVG elliptical Command A. 
it would be great if we can give an example of UIbezier Curve (Cubic / Quadratic cureve) that corresponds to the following Command :
"M600,350 l 50,-25 
           a25,25 -30 0,1 50,-25 l 50,-25 
           a25,50 -30 0,1 50,-25 l 50,-25 
           a25,75 -30 0,1 50,-25 l 50,-25 
           a25,100 -30 0,1 50,-25 l 50,-25"

Thank you !

Comment: Could you add an image you want to receive?

Comment: Do you mean "at all", or do you mean "is there anything built into the IOS APIs that let me do this"? Because the answer to the first is "yes, but the math is hard and the explanation long", whereas the answer to the second is "there might be, let us know if you can't find them, after [looking for them yourself, first](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)."

Comment: Thank you Mike for your quick answer. I meant if there is a way to describe the Arc command with just the following UIBezierPath Methods : **moveToPoint, addCurveToPoint:controlPoint1:controlPoint2:** instead of **addArcWithCenter**